# Spring Boot metrics for Prometheus using Micrometer or Spring Metrics

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-micrometer

I am building a Spring Boot application and planning to use the `/actuator/prometheus` for data scraping by Prometheus. It seems that the main way is to use Micrometer. However, I see that there is another library, which is [Spring Metrics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-metrics/docs/current/public/prometheus).

What is the go to way to have custom metrics that will be scraped by prometheus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Early in its development, Micrometer was named Spring Metrics. If you got to the project's GitHub repository (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-metrics) you will see that it redirects to https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer as the repository was moving into the `micrometer-metrics` organization and renamed.

In short, you should use Micrometer.